# Output resistors and GPIO

Tags: gpio, wiringpi

I am planning to control a IC (CD74HCT299E). I have currently GPIO-pins directly hooked up to the IC. My Question is, does the Raspberry pi have resistors before the GPIO-pin, or do I have to or should I add my own resistor between the chip and the GPIO-pin.
(If anyone is interested, I'm using this programm to try to read the chip: [Github CD74HCT299](https://github.com/C0D3-M4513R/CD74HCT299/tree/development))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear as you don't say whether you're using the GPIO as 1) input, 2) output, or 3) both. Your options will depend upon your usage - i.e. 1), 2) or 3).

#### First Recommendation:

Replace the `CD74HCT299E` with a `CD74HC299E` (**note the missing `T`**). The `CD74HC299E` has a Supply Voltage Range (VCC) from 2V to 6V. Therefore it will interface directly with the RPi GPIO pins at 3.3V without need for voltage dividers or *level shifters*. See this [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc299.pdf) for further details on your *299 shift register.

This recommendation will cover **all cases**: 1), 2) & 3).

#### Other Recommendations:

If for some reason you are wedded to the 4.5V-5.5V part - CD74HC`T`299E, and your usage case is **1) ONLY** (GPIO as input), then a resistive voltage divider should work. Note this IS NOT a single series resistor as implied in your question, but a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider).

If your usage case is **2) ONLY** (GPIO as output), you should add a *level shifter* (some examples sourced by [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/395) and [TI](http://www.ti.com/document-viewer/LSF0108/datasheet/features-sdls9669737#SDLS9669737)) to get the GPIO outputs up to 4.5V.

The `T` in the part number indicates this part was built (and presumably guaranteed) to meet [TTL levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic) which would *probably* cover the RPi's GPIO specs for high and low. However, the RPi is **not** a TTL device, and I believe a level shifter will improve the reliability across this interface.

Note also that in general level shifters may be *uni*-directional or *bi*-directional. Using a bi-directional shifter will cover use cases **1) AND 2)**.

If you need help sizing the resistors for the voltage divider, please let us know.

Comment: There is a Line in the Documentation for the HCT variation saying: V_IH = 2V

Comment: Whelp, just build a couple level uni-directional level shifters, and everything is working as expected. Thanks

Comment: @C0D3M4513R: Re V_IH - I stand corrected! I'll edit my answer. But I'll stick by my recommendation. The `T` in the part number was used for an entire class of CMOS devices that were developed to be compatible with [TTL logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transistor%E2%80%93transistor_logic). Happy to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

The HCT variants are 4.5-6V.  They may not be controllable from the Pi's 3V3 GPIO.

You don't need in-line resistors between the chip pins and the Pi pins.

However if the chip is being driven from more than 3V3 you will need to construct a voltage divider between the chip's output pin and the corresponding Pi input GPIO (to drop the voltage to a Pi safe 3V3).

Comment: In the Documentation of that chip is stated, that a pin is considered high, if V>2. So 3V3 shouldn't be a problem, right?